# Delete Row from DataGridView in C# windows Form

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to Delete Row from DataGridView in C# windows Form, my codes Works just for once then

```
                    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Delete")
                    {
                        try
                        {



                        using (con = new SqlConnection(C))
                        {
                            using (objCom = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Crud where Id = @Id;SELECT id as 'Customer Id' , Ch_Code as 'Customer Code' , Ch_Name as 'Customer Name',Ch_Type as 'Type' FROM Crud", con))
                            {
                                objCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value);
                                using ( objAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(objCom))
                                {


                                    objAdp.Fill(DS,"xyz");
                                    dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables["xyz"].DefaultView;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        }
                        catch (Exception EX)
                        {

                            MessageBox.Show(EX.Message);
                        }
                    }
```

it gives me exception

> conversion failed when converting the nvarchar valur 'Delete' to data
>   type int

Comment: Your `dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value` seems have `Delete` as an `object`. How do you think you can delete this value which only can have integer values called `Id` column?

Answer (score 0):

The practice of using `AddWithValue` is a good one for avoiding Sql Injections. but, when using the `.Value` member, you need to make sure that your `Value` won't contain a string while you need to pass integer for your dynamic transaction.

One thing to do is to convert your value to Int32, which will then be a valid int and perhaps won't return the error.

Your second option  is to use SqlDbType.Int conversion. this way you will be sure to insert an integer acceptable by the database. like this:

```
(SqlDbType.Int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
```

Comment: I don't think this will compile since `SqlDbType.Int` is not a `type`.

Comment: It might not, but it was an example, since .Value is of Nullable(T).Value property. It will always contain a string or a boolean value, not a numeric value. This is why the code fails.

Comment: No. `Value` returns `object` not `Nullable<T>` or something else. You are working with C# types with your casting, not database types. `nvarchar` is irrelevant here.

Comment: But this object contains a string right now, equal to nvarchar in database terms. this is why it is failing from first place, he is trying to pass a string where an int is needed.

Comment: Oh wait.. I read the error message again. Looks like this `Value` includes `Delete` string which can not hold for an integer column.

Comment: Thank you for your response .
 i slightly change the code 

if (e.ColumnIndex == "index number")

but this code works only for one time. 
then after that it stop working .